# making debug code and release code equal in visual studio 2012 express

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012, ide

I'm a beginner with visual studio 2012 express and applications development in general. Right now I have release code that is spot on to what I want the app to do and output.  When I change the selector to debug, I get output that is about two iterations back, and which does not match the code I'm seeing in the editor screen. How do I make the debug code equal to the release code in the IDE?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in the codebase between the two configurations.  Perhaps you have some conditionally compiled code?

Answer (score 0):

One source of distinction between Release and Debug builds is any code that using the #DEBUG directive. This will only exist in the debug version. Another less obvious source of distinction is the solution build configuration:

1. Right-click on the Solution and click Properties.
2. Go to Configuration Properties --> Configuration.
3. Toggle between Debug and Release on the Configuration drop-down box at the top left, and look for any differences in Platform or the Build check box.

One other thing you could try is a rebuild - right-click on Solution and click Rebuild.

Comment: Checking the configuration properties, there seems to be no difference at that level. Changing the configurations in the toolbar doesn't change the code in the editor window, but when I run the debugger, the debug code being compiled is different than the release code being shown in the editor window. Rebuild makes no difference, the same behavior is exhibited.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and some by-guess-by-golly work, it seems that selecting the debug configuration and then under the build menu selecting clean solution.  Then build the solution again and voila, the right code is used and the two configurations once again track. Thank you to all for your inputs.